# How to pass the random numbers from an array to get each object property from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have generated unique numbers from 1 to 3:

```
let arrayOfNums = [];

while (arrayOfNums.length < 3) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  if (arrayOfNums.indexOf(r) === -1) arrayOfNums.push(r);
}
console.log(arrayOfNums);
```

I have another array of 3 objects:

```
colors = [
  {
    name: "red",
    colorValue: "red",
    label: "r",
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    colorValue: "yellow",
    label: "y",
  },
  {
    name: "blue",
    colorValue: "#0077FF",
    label: "b",
  },
];

let randomNumber;
colors[randomNumber].colorValue
```

How do I loop through every element inside `arrayOfNums` and then pass each element (or int) onto the object getter (`[randomNumber]`) to get every colorValue randomly?

Please help me 'cause I'm kind of new in Javascript and I really don't know how to do this. It's so complex so please help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: are you asking how to do a for-loop to go through the values in `arrayOfNums`?

Comment: Yes and then use those values from the `arrayOfNums` to get every `colorValue` inside the `colors`.

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian, Do you mean like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/OJMRJNX  .. Look at console..

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian, Glad to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of each index, So you need to change,

```
let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
```

**to**

```
let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
```

Then you can get use of [**array.forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate each item and get the color values like,

```
arrayOfNums.forEach(item => console.log(colors[item].colorValue))
```

And the working **snippet** as follows,

```js
let arrayOfNums = [];

while (arrayOfNums.length < 3) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (arrayOfNums.indexOf(r) === -1) arrayOfNums.push(r);
}
console.log(arrayOfNums);

colors = [
  {
    name: "red",
    colorValue: "red",
    label: "r",
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    colorValue: "yellow",
    label: "y",
  },
  {
    name: "blue",
    colorValue: "#0077FF",
    label: "b",
  },
];

arrayOfNums.forEach(item => console.log(colors[item].colorValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-loop seems to be what you're asking for. This should work:

```
for (let i=0; i<arrayOfNums.length; i++) {
  let randomNumber = arrayOfNums[i];
  colors[randomNumber].colorValue  // use this however you need 
}
```

The above is the basic form. It can be done more efficiently like this:

```
for (const num of arrayOfNums) {
  colors[num].colorValue // use this however you need 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
for (let num of arrayOfNums){
    let randomNumber = num;
    console.log("Your random color: "+colors[randomNumber].colorValue);
}
```